# Bootstrap 4 move image out of the card header's container

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

I am trying to achieve something like this:

[image] as you can see I am using Bootstrap 4 cards for this, the problem is that I don't really understand what is the best way how to move the icon / image out of the Cards header? I have tried a couple css position tricks, but no success. At the moment I have this [Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/4cTSIvWwcP)

Comment: Link to one of the possible solutions(maybe) - https://codepen.io/bubblesphere/pen/QEVqyR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the best and most clean way is to use relative position with negative margin on the top of the image.

Here is an example:

```
<img src="/images/my_image.png" style="position: relative; margin-top: -31px;">
```

Answer (score 3):

Since I'm not too familiar with bootstrap, I can at least explain how to do it without.

```css
body {
background-color: #e6e6e6;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

}
#container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  
}
#container #bottom-card {
  background-color: white;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
#container img {
  width: 90%;
  transform: translateY(50px);
  margin-left: 10px;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">



<img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-WasxwVSbP9o/U2iH8PGuHMI/AAAAAAAADlw/igcKXRFaZ1k/s1600/clio_car-vector.png"></img>


<div id="bottom-card">

Content
</div>

</div>




</body>
</html>
```

It's as easy as creating a container to hold it all, and then create a div inside of the container which will be the white card on the bottom. I applied the following style to the image to position it correctly. In the end, it should look like this:[image]